# Kohana - database config per environment

Tags: database, kohana, config, environment, kohana-3.3

I want to set in my bootstrap the right config I will use functions of the environment.
I try to use

```
Database::instance('my_conf');
```

or

```
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_File('config/'.$environment));
```

This isn't working....

Any idea ?

Kohana version: 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - In your bootstrap, after loading Model module, write:

```
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_File('config/'.$_SERVER['YOUR_ENV']));
```

2 - Create in folder config a subfolder "foobar" of the name $_SERVER['YOUR_ENV']

3 - Put in it your file   >   config/foobar/database.php  | don't change "default" key

```
return array
(
    'default' => array
    (
        // your config
    )
)
```

4 - Set in apache :

```
SetEnv YOUR_ENV foobar
```

And it works !!